# Bootcamp OSX Mojave - cannot open any files on windows partition - dot_clean error

Tags: macos, terminal, macos-mojave, bootcamp

I am (once again) experiencing the -36 error saying that some files cannot be read or written, which I suspect must be a side-effect of my recent OSX Mojave update.

Google tells me that error can be fixed by running `dot_clean` in Terminal and point it at the affected folder/volume. Now, the problem here is that my whole `Windows 10` volume is affected by this error, but when trying to point terminal to `dot_clean /Volumes/Windows 10/` it throws an error saying that it cant find folder `/Volumes/Windows`.

The problem here is obviously that `dot_clean` doesnt support spaces in volume names, hence I am wondering how I can run the command on my windows partition?

Thanks for any help,
A2k

Answer (score 1):

OK, turn out that Terminal escapes spaces by using "\ " before a space.

Example:
Volume Name: `Windows 10`
Terminal command: `dot_clean /Volumes/Windows\ 10`

Hope that helps,
A2k

Comment: Alternatively: `dot_clean "/Volumes/Windows 10"` or `dot_clean '/Volumes/Windows 10'`